# Clustering word boxes into text blocks

Tags: computer-vision, ocr, google-vision, text-recognition, east-text-detector

I have a huge collection of images where I perform Google OCR and retrieve the location of the texts (my main purpose is to detect the texts, not recognizing). Google does a pretty good job at detecting individual words or even letters. However the situation is not the same for recognizing text blocks or paragraphs.

The results for words:

[image: words]

The results for paragraphs:

[image: paragraph]

And text blocks:

[image: text blocks]

I want to seperate each text block (at least columns just for now) so that I can do some extra operations, which is out of the scope of this question. What is the way of merging these individual word boxes into one big block of text? I tried to fill each box with rectangle so it is easier to do some operations with OpenCV (like the following, a different picture from above)

[image: filled rectangles example]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65541996/python-opencv-intersection-of-multiple-rectangles/65544613#65544613

Comment: @stateMachine isn't this solution about removing intersection areas between boxes? or am i missing something?